# how to save color in sqlite in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

i am developing a todo app that contains a tag part and a task part.
each tag contains a title and a color so i needs to store tag color in sqlite db.
here is my tag table columns :

```
db.execute('''
              create table tags ( 
                  id integer primary key autoincrement,
                  title text not null,
                  color text not null
                  )
              ''');
```

and here i send my tag model to insert db method :

```
new TagModel(
                                    title: _addTagTitleController.text,
                                    color: _currentColor.value.toString(),
                                  ),
```

any idea will be greate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the int value of the color in the db.

```
int value = Colors.white.value; //save this in your database.
```

Then for using it again, retrieve the int value and do this,

```
Color newColor = Color(value); //value refers to the int value saved in the database
```